# Hibernate INSERT, delayed SQL error (DATA TRUNCATION)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My application parses a CSV file, about 100 - 200 records per file, does database CRUD features and commits them all in the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
         List<Row> rows = parseCSV();

         Transaction t = openHibernateTransaction();

         //doCrudStuff INSERTS some records in the database
         for (Row r : rows)
             doCrudStuff(r);

         t.commit();

     } catch (Exception ex) {
           //log error
           if (t != null) t.rollback();
     }
}
```

When I was about to `doCrudStuff` on the 78th `Row`, I suddenly got this error:
`Data truncation: Data too long for column 'SOME_COLUMN_UNRELATED_TO_78TH_ROW' at row 1`.

I read the stack trace and the error was triggered by a `SELECT` statement to a table unrelated to the 78th row. Huh, weird right?

I checked the CSV file and found that on the 77th row, some field was indeed too long for the database column. But Hibernate didn't catch the error during the `INSERT` of the 77th row and threw the error when I was doing a `SELECT` for the 78th row. Why is it delayed?

Does Hibernate really behave like this? I commit only once at the very end because I want to make sure that everything succeeded, otherwise, rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually not really if you take into account what hibernate is doing behind the scenes for you.

Hibernate does not actually execute your write statements (update,insert) until it needs to, thus in your case I assume your "doCrudStuff" executes a select and then executes an update or insert right?

This is what is happening:

You tell hibernate to execute "UPDATE my_table SET something = value;" which causes hibernate to cache this in the session and return right away.

You may do more writes, which Hibernate will likely continue to cache in the session until either 1) you manually flush the session or 2) hibernate decides its time to flush the session.

You then execute a SELECT statement to get some data from the database. At this point, the state of the database is not consistent with the state of the session since there is data waiting to be written. Hibernate will then start executing your writes to catch up the database state to the session state.

If one of the writes fails, when you look at the stack trace, you will actually not be able to map it to the exact point you **asked** (this a important distinction between an ORM and using JDBC directly) hibernate to execute the write, but rather it will fail when the session had to be flushed (either manually or automatically).

At the expense of performance, you can always tell hibernate to flush your session after your writes. But as long as you are aware of the lifecycle of the hibernate session and how it caches those queries, you should be able to more easily debug these.

By the way, if you want to see this is practice, you can tell hibernate to log the queries.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** I understand how this can be confusing, let me try to augment my answer by highlighting the difference between a Transaction and a Hibernate Session.

A [transaction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190612%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a sequence of atomic operations **performed on the database**. Until a transaction is committed, it is typically not visible by other clients of the database. The state of the transaction is fully managed by the database - i.e. you can start a transaction and send you operations to the database, and it will ensure consistency of these operations within the transaction.

A [Hibernate Session](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_sessions.htm) is a session managed by Hibernate, outside the database, mostly for performance reasons. Hibernate will queue operations whenever possible to improve performance, and only go to the database when it deems necessary.

Imagine you have 50 marbles that are all different colors and need to be stored in their correct buckets, but these buckets are 100 feet away and you need someone to correctly sort them inside their rightful buckets. You ask your friend Bob to store the blue marbles, then the red marbles then the green marbles. Your friend is smart and anticipates that you will ask him to make multiple round trips, so he ways until your last request to walk those 100 feet to store them in their proper buckets, which is much faster than making 3 round trips.

Now imagine that you ask him to store the yellow marbles, and then you ask him how many total marbles you have across all the buckets. He is then forced to go to the buckets (since he needs to gather information), store the yellow marbles (so he can accurately count all buckets) before he can give you an answer. This is in essence what hibernate is doing with your data.

How in your case, imagine there is NO yellow bucket. Bob unfortunately is not going to find that out until he tries to answer your query into how many total marbles you have - thus in the sequence of events, he will come back to you to tell you he couldn't complete your request only after he tries to count the marbles (as opposed to when you asked him to store the yellow ones, which is what he was actually unable to do).

Hope this helps clear things a little bit!

Comment: Hibernate will start executing my writes but it won't commit unless 1) Hibernate's set to auto-commit=true or 2) transaction.commit() is invoked... am I getting this right?